# What is the default tolerance for ETRS89 in geospatial operations if the user does not specify any?

Tags: geospatial, marklogic

In Marklogic I'm using [`cts.geospatialRegionQuery`](https://docs.marklogic.com/cts.geospatialRegionQuery) to search for documents that contain (an indexed) geometry that has an intersection with the geometry I search with.

The geospatial region index uses `etrs89/double` as coordinate system. All geometries in the data have 9 decimal places.

According to the Marklogic [Geospatial search applications documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/geospatial#id_64742):

> [...] geospatial queries against single precision indexes are accurate to within 1 meter for geodetic coordinate systems.

I would, therefore, expect that my queries would have sub-meter accuracy. However, I get search results from `cts.geospatialRegionQuery` containing geometries up to ~5 meters away from my search geometry. As far as I can see the only reason for this could be the `tolerance` option that I'm not specifying yet and is therefore using the default.

The [documentation](https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/geospatial#id_55457) mentions that

> If you do not explicitly set tolerance, MarkLogic uses the default tolerance appropriate for the coordinate system.
>   To ensure accuracy, MarkLogic enforces a minimum tolerance for each coordinate system.

This brings us to the actual question:

What is the default (and minimum) tolerance for the etrs89 coordinate system in Marklogic?

**EDIT:**
Looked further into the issue with help from Marklogic Support and found the cause of the low accuracy of my geospatial queries.

Before using `cts.geospatialRegionQuery` I parsed the search geometry with `geo.parseWkt`. This function does not allow you to explicitly set the coordinate system to be used and therefore uses the coordinate system set in the AppServer settings. By default this is single precision wgs84. This lead to a loss of 2-3 digits on my search geometry.

After setting the coordinate system to etrs89/double in the AppServer settings, `geo.parseWkt` didn't reduce the precision of the search geometry anymore and my geospatial queries had the expected 5 mm accuracy.

Comment: Just a thought here: I assume you tested this with explicitly setting 0 tolerance and you still got the same result (i.e. false value). If your data has double precision, have you properly configured you geospatial indexes to use double precision? If you didn't do this, they will by default use single precision which might be the reason for the results you see...

Comment: Yes, I tested with explicitly setting 0 tolerance and got the same result. And yes, the geospatial index has been configured correctly.

Comment: In that case, you might have found a bug - congratulations! (and support will help you)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default tolerance for WGS84 and ETRS89 coordinate systems is 0.5cm for double precision and 5 meters for single precision.

Answer (score 1):

Closing the loop on this issue using feedback provided by MarkLogic support:

When setting up the query geo.ParseWkt was used to create the POINT and as this function does not take a coordinate system or precision as options the result was being truncated to 8 significant digits by default. In the Latitude they were working this reduced precision from 0.5cm to 5m leading to the observed results.

```
geo.parseWkt("POINT(5.176605744 52.045696539)");
```

Results in:

```
POINT(5.1766057 52.045697)
```

When using JavaScript the solution is to set the correct coordinate system in the AppServer, see  https://docs.marklogic.com/guide/search-dev/geospatial#id_77035 and following example (written in XQuery):

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
import module namespace admin = "http://marklogic.com/xdmp/admin" at "/MarkLogic/admin.xqy";

let $config := admin:get-configuration()
let $groupid := admin:group-get-id($config, "Default")
return admin:save-configuration(
admin:appserver-set-coordinate-system(
$config,
admin:appserver-get-id($config, $groupid, "App-Services"),
"etrs89/double")
```

Once this was done the POINT created using geo.ParseWkt had the correct level of precision.

With XQuery you can declare the coordinate system directly in the query:

```
declare option xdmp:coordinate-system "etrs89/double";
```